# Can't get Group policy preference to apply

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I have problems with file associations on a Windows Server 2008r2 terminal server. I have a GPO that was working up until a day or so that associated IrfanViewer for jpg and jpeg files. The GPO was for the user configuration. Today a tried to achieve the same thing through computer configuration and I kind of hit a wall there because the GPO is not getting applied. I'll show the preference and you tell me if that is ok:

[image]

Comment: How are you applying the GPO?  Is it linked to an OU containing the computer(s) you want it to affect?

Comment: A "Create" GPO will only apply once so if you're trying to get a machine that's "supposedly" already had it to re-add/amend an existing association then you may want to try using "Replace" under the preference "Action". This will re-apply whenever a GPUpdate is done...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, guess the old "delete&recreate" did the trick again. I (re)created the "same" gpo with the same association set up in the user configuration (as it was before),  applied the gpo to the user container, logged off, logged on and, it works.

Wish i tried this yesterday...

Nonetheless, ty for the comments/suggestions.